# PyQT5 - Add line one by one using a pause

Tags: python, pyqt5, sleep

The following code draw single random lines every merry one second. What I would like to do is to keep each line already drawn. What is the best way to do that ?

I know that I need to use a `QTimer` to do a responsive user interface but first I need to know how to draw more and more lines...

Maybe one way would be to draw all lines hidden and to show more and more lines... Or must I use a `QGraphicsView` ?

```
from random import random
import sys
from time import sleep

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer


LINES = [
    (500*random(), 500*random(), 500*random(), 500*random())
    for _ in range(50)
]

class Interface(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.max    = len(LINES)
        self.cursor = 0

        self.painter = QPainter()

        self.setFixedSize(500, 500)
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        self.painter.begin(self)
        self.drawsetpbystep()
        self.painter.end()

    def drawsetpbystep(self):
        if self.cursor < self.max:
            self.painter.drawLine(*LINES[self.cursor])
            self.update()
            sleep(0.25)

        self.cursor += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    interface = Interface()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve it? You already have enough reputation to know that SO is not a coding service.

Comment: @eyllanesc Question just updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to use sleep in a GUI, and in the case of PyQt it is very dangerous, because Qt offers alternatives to create the same effect as QTimer, QEventLoop, etc.

Another error is that the QPainter has a very large life cycle, it should only be created and called in paintEvent.

And the last mistake is wanting to pause the task of paintEvent since you're doing it through the drawsetpbystep method. the paintEvent method not only will you use it but actually uses the application whenever you need it, the right thing to do is use a flag to indicate when you should paint as shown below:

```
LINES = [
    (500*random(), 500*random(), 500*random(), 500*random())
    for _ in range(50)
]

class Interface(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.max    = len(LINES)
        self.cursor = 0
        self.show()

        self.paint = False

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.onTimeout)
        timer.start(250)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        if self.paint:
            self.drawsetpbystep(painter)

    def onTimeout(self):
        self.paint = True
        self.update()

    def drawsetpbystep(self, painter):
        if self.cursor < self.max:
            painter.drawLine(*LINES[self.cursor])
            self.cursor += 1
        self.paint = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    interface = Interface()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Great and clear ! It remains one little big problem : keep each new line plotted.

Comment: I have edited the answer above such as to keep each lines drawn.

Comment: Do you want the lines to be maintained?

Answer (score 1):

Using `time.sleep` in PyQt applications is not recommended because it blocks execution of the Qt event loop which is responsible for handling user input (via keyboard and mouse) and actually drawing the application window.

Instead, you should use `QTimer` to schedule execution of a specified method at the times you want. In this case, you probably want to use multiple `QTimer.singleShot` calls. Likely the first method called by the timer will draw one point/line and then set up a timer to call another method which will draw one point/line and set up a timer to call another method...etc. etc.

Comment: I have updated my question : there is a minimal none working example...